# python Pandas lambda apply doesn't work for NaN

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

been trying to do an efficient vlookup style on pandas, with IF function...

Basically, I want to apply to this column ccy_grp, that if the value (in a particular row) is 'NaN', it will take the value from another column ccy

```
def func1(tkn1, tkn2):
    if tkn1 == 'NaN:
        return tkn2
    else:
        return tkn1
    
tmp1_.ccy_grp = tmp1_.apply(lambda x: func1(x.ccy_grp, x.ccy), axis = 1)
```

but nope, doesn't work. The code cannot seem to detect 'NaN'. I tried another way of np.isnan(tkn1), but I just get a boolean error message...

Any experienced python pandas code developer know?

Comment: In general, use [`math.isnan(tkn1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan) to detect NaN, since normal comparisons fail (NaN is not equal to anything, including itself: `math.nan != math.nan`). But with a Pandas DataFrame, [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) is much more efficient for what you seem to be doing.

Comment: Please make this a fully running script including a small, example dataframe. We shouldn't have to cook that up ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pandas method for what you are trying to do. Check out [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

> Update null elements with value in the same location in ‘other’.
>
> Combine two Series objects by filling null values in one Series with
> non-null values from the other Series.

```
tmp1_.ccy_grp = tmp1_.ccy_grp.combine_first(tmp1_.ccy)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### use `pandas.isna` to detect a value whether a `NaN`

1. generate data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'value':[np.NAN, None, 1,2,3],
                     'label':['str:np.NAN', 'str: None', 'str: 1', 'str: 2', 'str: 3']})
data
```

[image]

2. create a function

```py
def func1(x):
    if pd.isna(x):
        return 'is a na'
    else:
        return f'{x}'
```

3. apply function to data

```py
data['func1_result'] = data['value'].apply((lambda x: func1(x)))
data
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should be a pandas `mask/where/fillna` problem, not an `apply`:

Given:

```
   value  values2
0    NaN      0.0
1    NaN      0.0
2    1.0      1.0
3    2.0      2.0
4    3.0      3.0
```

Doing:

```
df.value.fillna(df.values2, inplace=True)
print(df)

# or

df.value.mask(df.value.isna(), df.values2, inplace=True)
print(df)

# or 

df.value.where(df.value.notna(), df.values2, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   value  values2
0    0.0      0.0
1    0.0      0.0
2    1.0      1.0
3    2.0      2.0
4    3.0      3.0
```